# How to get mapStateToProps value from a function to class component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I using react to develop a web application.

Requirement:
My requirement is, i have a function component which will content my mapStateToProps function and i will call that function component from my class component.So that my repetition of the code will get reduce.

Problem:
Now the problem with this is, when i write the mapStateToProps in my function component and then i call it from my class component it dose't get executed

```js
class: A.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import b from './B'

export class A extends Component {

    submit = () => {
        b();
    } 
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={this.submit}>Submit</Button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default A



functional Component: B.js
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const b = () => {
    let data = {
        name = props.details.name
    }
    return data;
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        name: state.detailReducer.name
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(b);
```

Help:
So can any one help me how i can achieve this requirement. It will be very helpful.
And also please tell me is it a good way to call the mapStateToProps from the other function compoent.

Comment: b doesn't look like react component. it's a normal function which returns some wrong syntax object.

Comment: what is your goal `onSubmit()`? `b` doesn't return a `jsx` only a string. plus, your props is `props.name` and **not** `props.details.name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to distinguish functions and function components. In your `Component` `A` you are using `b` as a function, although it *should be* be a function component. That you cannot do. A function component is meant being *rendered* not *executed*.

Also to make `b` an actual function component, `b` is missing props in the argument list and it should be `props.name` instead of `props.details.name` and it needs to return `JSX`. And finally it should called `B`.